# How to detect if there is any change in value of dom element value(e.g. any input or check box value changed) using Java Script after rendering page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this case, challenge is dom elements are created dynamically for different request and total number of dom elements are not fixed [e.g. may be 1 or multiple no of rows].

For example table/dom elements are created when there is a response from the web service. There is a save button on the web page but it will enabled only when there is any change on one of the element [change should not be identical to the last value].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function's **event delegation** syntax to bind `change` event handlers to your inputs. Something like this:

```
$(document).on('input', 'change', function() {
    // enable your 'Save' button
});
```

There's more information about event delegation in the linked API page, particularly the *Direct and delegated events* section.

Note that the `.on()` function was introduced in jQuery 1.7. If you're using a version prior to that, you can get the same result using the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function instead - just switch the first two arguments around.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, how would we get if the changes are identical or not. E.g. previous value is 1 and then value is changed to 2 and then again to 1. Is there any way to handle such case ?

Comment: @neo Use an HTML5 `data-*` attribute to store the initial value for all of your inputs, then compare the current value to that when the `change` event is fired.